# ASP.NET Async Tasks - how to use WebClient.DownloadStringAsync with Page.RegisterAsyncTask

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

A common task I have to do for a site I work on is the following:

- Download data from some third-party API
- Process the data in some fashion
- Display the results on the page

I was initially using WebClient.DownloadStringAsync and doing my processing on the result. However I was finding that DownloadStringAsync was not respecting the AsyncTimeout parameter, which I sort of expected once I did a little reading about how this works.

I ended up adapting the code from [the example on how to use PageAsyncTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx) to use DownloadString() there - please note, it's the synchronous version. This is probably okay, because the task is now asynchronous. The tasks now properly time out and I can get the data by PreRender() time - and I can easily genericize this and put it on any page I need this functionality.

However I'm just worried it's not 'clean'. The page isn't notified when the task is done like the DownloadStringAsync method would do - I just have to scoop the results (stored in a field in the class) up at the end in my PreRender event.

Is there any way to get the Webclient's Async methods to work with RegisterPageTask, or is a helper class the best I can do?

Notes: No MVC - this is vanilla asp.net 4.0.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "The page isn't notified when the task is done"?

The call to Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks() is a blocking call, so the "notification" is when that call completes. You're either calling that method manually, or, if the async tasks were registered before PreRender, it's being called automatically by the page pipeline within System.Web.dll

If you're wanting to know precisely when the task ends, then wouldn't that be what the two EndEventHandlers on the PageAsyncTask object are for?

Comment: I don't get an event called (a method in the page would be ideal) when the task is complete... I just get the results in the class and I have to pick them up later. If the call is blocking, then I guess it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an event handler on your Page called when the async task completes, you need only hook one up. To expand on the MSDN "how to" article you linked:

1. Modify the "SlowTask" class to include an event, like - `public event EventHandler Finished;`
2. Call that EventHandler in the "OnEnd" method, like - `if (Finished != null)
           {
               Finished(this, EventArgs.Empty);
           }`
3. Register an event handler in your page for SlowTask.Finished, like - `mytask.Finished += new EventHandler(mytask_Finished);`

Regarding ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks() being a blocking call, that's based only on my experience. It's not documented explicitly as such in the MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.executeregisteredasynctasks.aspx

That said, it wouldn't be all that practical for it be anything *BUT* a blocking call, given that it doesn't return a WaitHandle or similar. If it didn't block the pipeline, the Page would render and be returned to the client before the async task(s) completed, making it a little difficult to get the results of the task back to the client.

Comment: Simple enough, and makes sense. The lack of explicit documentation is what threw me. Thanks!